# How to negate a lambda function result

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda

In the following there is a code snippet written in C++ which does not compile.
The reason is trying to reverse the result of a lambda function using not1(). I'll appreciate very much if someone could fix this code

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
using namespace std;
#include <functional>   // std::not1
#include <algorithm>    // std::count_if
#include <vector>

int main () {
    vector<int> sv = {3, 5, 10,12 };
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    auto validSelection = [&](auto& e) {
        auto isSelected = [&] (auto& sve) {
            return e == sve;
        };
        return find_if(sv.begin(), sv.end(), isSelected) != sv.end();
    };
    stable_partition(v.begin(), next(v.begin(),8) , not1(validSelection));
    for (int n : v) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty shure that „does not compile“ is not the error message.

Comment: why not use a lambda to do the `notl`, it's more clear (at least to me).

Comment: @appleapple especially when  this code already using lambda where it is not necessary

Comment: smallest change: `return find_if(sv.begin(), sv.end(), isSelected) == sv.end();`

Comment: @manni66 just copy and paste the snippet and compile it with your compiler. You will see a full of window error messages which are beyond of my understanding to interprate .  If you can give me a hint on how to interprate that error messages I'll appreciate very much.

Comment: @SabetayToros definitely not!

Answer (score 2):

One of approaches is to use the wrapper `std::function`. For example

```
auto even = [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; };

std::cout << std::not1(std::function<bool(int)>(even))(11) << std::endl;
```

The function object adapter `not1` requires that the corresponding predicate used as argument had typedef names `argument_type` and `result_type` and the wrapper `std::function` provides them.

In your case the equivalent call would look like this:

```
stable_partition(v.begin(), next(v.begin(), 8) , not1(function<bool(int&)>(validSelection)));
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/Epi94K)

Or if I have understood correctly what you are trying to do then the corresponding code can look as it is shown in the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> sv = { 3, 5, 10, 12 };
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };

    auto validSelection = [&](int x)
    {
        return std::binary_search(sv.begin(), sv.end(), x);
    };

    std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), validSelection);

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), std::not1( std::function<bool( int )>( validSelection) ) );

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the output is

```
3 5 10 12 1 2 4 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 15
1 2 4 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 15 3 5 10 12
```

Pay attention to using of the algorithm `std::binary_search` because the vector `sv` is sorted.

Comment: You should explain why it does not work without wrapper - "The unary predicate type must define a member type, argument_type, that is convertible to the predicate's parameter type."

Comment: In reality the vector is not sorted.  it is written like that for demo purpose.

Comment: @SabetayToros In this case you can substitute the call of std::binary search for the expression std::find( .. ) != sv.end()

Comment: You might want to mention C++17 [`std::not_fn()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn), which is much improved.

Comment: `std::not1` and `std::not2` were [deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional#Deprecated_in_C.2B.2B17_and_removed_in_C.2B.2B20). `std::not_fn()` is definitely the one to use now.